# Does the fact that China owns nuclear weapon improve the status of Chinese expat?

Tags: china, military, nuclear-weapons, racism

According to Chinese government propaganda, it is because of the development and deployment of nuclear weapons that the status of Chinese ex-pats is no longer discriminated against by anyone else. Are there any documents or research that can prove that there is a direct link between the increasing military might of the PRC and the fact there are fewer anti-Chinese riots and discriminatory acts against a Chinese in western bloc nations (US, Canada, Europe in particular) between mid-1960s to 1990s

Comment: There are (relatively) many anti-Asian hate crimes in the United States, with an increase due to the COVID-19 pandemic. A lot of these are against Chinese people. So the argument that there is no longer discrimination seems to fail on the surface. Are there fewer than in the past? Sure, and there are also fewer anti-Irish and anti-Italian crimes, but neither of those countries has nuclear weapons. Also, no one believes that China would employ nuclear weapons against countries where Chinese immigrants were being discriminated against, so a deterrent effect seems unlikely.

Comment: There'd be a lot to check in that claim -- for example, we'd want to check that Chinese ex-pats actually are less discriminated against since China's gotten nuclear weapons, then check if there's some appreciable causation.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to have some survey of ex-pat discrimination over time vs. when their home-country went nuclear?

Comment: @Nat - That seems like an easy way to get confounding variables. Maybe anti-Chinese crimes decreased around the time of the US civil rights movement, which was also around the time China developed nuclear weapons. Or maybe China's increased wealth both enabled military advancement and raised the country's profile enough to combat stereotypes.

Comment: @Obie2.0: If there's an apparent-correlation, then sure, it wouldn't establish causation.  Though if there's no correlation, it'd seem helpful.  And the hypothesis seems pretty weak, so it might be prone to easy refutation.

Comment: Is this even an oft-repeated propaganda line to be worthy of an investigation? Because with billions upon billions of "brainstorming" nationalistic posts on the Chinese social media networks... one is bound to find "gems" like this. For the record, I'm not among the downvoters, it just that this seems a rather obscure (and fairly improbable) claim to me. I mean China's standing as world power was definitely improved by having nuclear weapons. How much that might have reduced anti-Chinese sentiment or racism is going to be hard to quantify.

Answer (score 2):

As the saying goes, history is an experiment with N=1. (That is, we don't have a second history where China did not have nuclear weapons, to compare. Or a third, and a fourth, and more, to do statistics.) I believe the following is obvious:

- The status of Chinese expat communities has improved *because* China is a superpower. One would also have to talk about *where*.  If there is upheaval somewhere in the world, one expects the US government to organize an airlift for their citizens. One expects the EU to try, and to be a little less effective than the US. In [parts of the world](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-28684555), China also does things like that.
- China's status as a superpower is enhanced by nuclear weapons.

What is arguable is just how much of that superpower status is due to the nuclear weapons. China traditionally had a concept of [minimal nuclear deterrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_deterrence), that is enough weapons to make a painful counterstrike, but no attempt to outfight the adversary. That, and a traditional lack of global military reach, reduced the impact of the military on Chinese status.

China has gotten more assertive lately, but mostly not in the nuclear arena. See [page 138 of this RAND study](https://www.rand.org/pubs/research_reports/RRA444-4.html).